# RBAC ClusterRole with permissons limited to namespace and also to create clusterrole

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Is their a way to create a ClusterRole using ClusterRolebinding that can provide permissions to create ClusterRoles/ClusterRolebindings and also add a condition somehow it can be limited to one namespace and cannot create resources in other namespaces?

Since, ClusterRole and ClusterRolebinding are not namespaced I'm looking for a way specifically for a way to provide permissions to create ClusterRole and ClusterRolebinding and then limit other resource creation specific to a namespace.

This cannot be achieved with RoleBinding since, it can only limit to namespace and cannot provide the permissions to create the non-namespaced resources.

Comment: Create `ClusterRole+ClusterRoleBinding` for giving only  ClusterRole creation permission and separate `Role+RoleBinding` for giving namespaced resource permissions.

Comment: Is their a way to do only with ClusterRole+ClusterRoleBinding?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand this is what you want to achieve:

1. You have a cluster admin access
2. You want to use this cluster admin access to create namespace admin(s)
3. You want these namespace admins to be able to grant access to other subject (e.g. users, groups or service accounts) to resources in that namespace.

If yes, then here is something you can try.

By default, your Kubernetes cluster comes with a set of default `ClusterRole` objects. In particular there are two default cluster roles that you will focus on:

1. edit
2. admin

Binding `edit` cluster role to a subject either by using `RoleBinding` or `ClusterRoleBinding` gives the subject access to edit most common resources like pods, deployments, secrets etc.

The `admin` cluster role however contains the accesses contained by the `edit` cluster role as well as accesses to additional namespaced resources, in particular to two resources that would be useful to administer a namespace:

1. Role
2. RoleBinding

If you bind this `admin` cluster role using `RoleBinding` to a subject within a specific namespace, you effectively give that subject the capabilities to administer the namespace, including creating another `RoleBinding` within that namespace to give some other subjects accesses to that namespace.

To illustrate:

```
You --(RoleBinding to admin ClusterRole)--> NamespaceAdmin
NamespaceAdmin --(RoleBinding to some Role or ClusterRole)--> OtherSubjects
```

Since `RoleBinding` is restricted to a specific namespace, the namespace admin will only have the `admin` accesses within that namespace only and cannot wreck havoc in other namespaces or at cluster level.